# Ansible with no action detected in task

Tags: ansible

I would like to check TLS/SSL certificate expiration date from Ansible.
After execute a valid YML (ansible-playbook TEST.yml) appears the following error:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to have been in '/scripts/Ansible/TEST.yml': line 15, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: check validity
      ^ here
```

This is the code:

```yaml
- name: find cerfication files & expiration dates
  hosts: 10.0.1.41
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Find cert files under /etc/pki/tls/certs
      find:
        paths: /etc/pki/tls/certs
        file_type: file
        patterns: "*.crt"
        recurse: yes
        excludes: "localhost.crt"
      register: find_result

    - name: check validity
      openssl_certificate_info:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        valid_at:
          point_1: "+1w"
          point_2: "+10w"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ find_result.files|flatten(levels=1) }}"

    - debug: msg= "{{ result }}"
```

What's the exactly wrong?

My version:

```
[root@ansible Ansible]# ansible-playbook --version
ansible-playbook 2.6.20
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jun 20 2019, 14:14:55) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are on a really old version of Ansible, I would recommend you to upgrade since your version had [an end of support long ago (November 6, 2019)](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/ansible-engine).

Now, the module you are trying to use didn't exist in the version 2.6, that's the reason for the error raised by Ansible.

In the version 2.6, the way to check a certificate was to use the [`openssl_certificate` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/openssl_certificate_module.html).

Something like:

```yaml
- name: check validity
  openssl_certificate:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    provider: assertonly
    valid_at: 20171221162800Z
  register: result
  loop: "{{ find_result.files }}"
```

Comment: I'm receiving a deprecation warning for using that module with "valid_at" at Ansible 2.9. I think one should use the x509_certificate module instead[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/crypto/x509_certificate_module.html]

Comment: @KevinC that wasn't accessible in 2.6 either: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/search.html?q=x509_certificate&check_keywords=yes&area=default